# Saving variable name using the .save function in Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm currently working on converting breastcancer scans into black and white photos. This code needs to scan every file in the directory, process it, and save it with a unique name. My code looks like this:

```
wd = os.getcwd()
lencounter = 0
for file in os.listdir(wd):
    lencounter += 1
for x in range(lencounter):
    for file in os.listdir(wd):
        if file.endswith("class0.png"):
            image_file = Image.open(file)    
            image_file= image_file.convert('L')
            image_file= image_file.convert('1')
            print(image_file, x)
            image_file.save("result1.png")
```

This code only allows me to save the last transformed picture, as "result1". Somehow the .save function doesn't let me include any iterationumber, just like you would expect when using the write() function.

I need something like "originalname_blackandwhite1.png" for every picture. I hope someone could help me out!

Thanks

Comment: The `save()` method _will_ allow you specify any valid filename you want (as a string value). Just create the name you want from the interation number (or any other data).

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, this should work

Answer (score 0):

What about `image_file.save("{}_blackandwhite1.png".format(x))`?

It can be more specific if you elaborate on how do you want your `originalname` to be